# align flex child at top-center and bottom-center, flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a layout using flexbox, where 2 flex-items, item-1 should be aligned at top-center, while item-2 should be at bottom-center. I could not figure out how to do that.

See the below code:

```css
.container{
  padding:10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin: 45px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0,1.1);
}

.item{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #3db5da;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item{
  /*margin: auto;*/
  /*align-self: flex-start;*/
}

.item-4{
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-4">
    Flex Item
    <p>Vertical and horizontal align easy!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-5"> bottom-center</div>
</div>
```

Here is fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/q5cw4xvy/

Comment: Change the `justify-content` property of the `.container` element to `space-between` and remove the `align-self` property from the 2nd child element.

Comment: you used the tag flex, please change this to flexbox to prevent confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `justify-content: space-between;` to align the items until the corners.
Add that to the `.container` and there you go.

```
.container{
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

On `.item-4` you have `align-self: flex-start;` but you don't need that. just remove it.

https://jsfiddle.net/q5cw4xvy/2/

To better help you understand flexbox, there is a really nice [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/da4jdff7/1/

```
.container{
display: flex;
min-height: 50vh;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}

.item-5 {
margin-top: auto
}
```